# Converting standard application to WP8 with WebClient

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have an application that does a lot of calls like

```
string html = getStringFromWeb(url);
//rest of processes use the html string
```

I'm trying to get application to Windows Phone, and the methodology there seems to be radically different:

```
void perform asynch call (...)

void handler
{ string html = e.Result
  //do things with it
}
```

1. Is getting html from webpage only possible using this asynch method?
2. How do i re-purpose the code so that i can work with html when i call for it?

Comment: Have you tried working with the asynchronous API? At least post your method call of `getStringFromWeb`.

Comment: Using HttpClient and the async/await keywords, you can write asynchronous code pretty much like you would write synchronous code. It'll save you a lot of time to convert your code

Comment: Thanks for the keywords KooKiz, this is the solution i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous methods return a `Task`. If you don't use `Wait()`, the code continues execution past the asynchronous method. If you don't want to use `Wait()`, you can create a asyncronous method with `Callback`-method as parameter.

**With Wait():**

```
// Asynchronous download method that gets a String
public async Task<string> DownloadString(Uri uri) {
   var task = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

   try {
      var client = new WebClient();
      client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => {
         task.SetResult(e.Result);
   };

   client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
      task.SetException(ex);
   }

   return await task.Task;
}

private void TestMethod() {
   // Start a new download task asynchronously
   var task = DownloadString(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com"));

   // Wait for the result
   task.Wait();

   // Read the result
   String resultString = task.Result;
}
```

**Or with Callback:**

```
private void TestMethodCallback() {

   // Start a new download task asynchronously
   DownloadString(new Uri("http://mywebsite.com"), (resultString) => {
      // This code inside will be run after asynchronous downloading
      MessageBox.Show(resultString);
   });

   // The code will continue to run here
}

// Downlaod example with Callback-method
public async void DownloadString(Uri uri, Action<String> callback) {

   var client = new WebClient();
   client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) => {
      callback(e.Result);
   };

   client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
}
```

Of course I recommend to use the Callback way, as it doesn't block the code from running while it's downloading the `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are working for web requests go for HttpWebRequest.

In windows phone 8 xaml/runtime you can do it by using HttpWebRequest or a WebClient.

> Basically WebClient is a wraper around HttpWebRequest.

If you have a small request to make then user HttpWebRequest. It goes like this

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestURI) as HttpWebRequest;
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
ObservableCollection<string> statusCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    string responseContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Do anything with you content. Convert it to xml, json or anything.
}
```

You can make this in a function which is basically an async method.

Coming to 1st question, all web requests will be made as async calls because it takes time to download based on your network. In order that the application not to be freezing, an async method will be used.

Comment: Thx for answer, but you are basically giving incomplete code and saying to stick into async method to a guy who asks about nature of async methods. Not exactly helpful.

Comment: @donkz You got the answer anyways. I need not edit now.